# Any good audio sources to learn programming?

Tags: audio, programming-languages

I currently work with computers everyday (although not programming) but I would like to learn some programming. I do not have any intend to work as a programmer but I would be able to get an understanding of code (being able to read code).

Ive started a bit of Python and liked it so far but one thing which I suppose is unavoidable is that I have to sit in front of a computer to learn it (test code, see the result etc). I know that's probably the optimal way to learn but it can become very boring at times and I am looking for other ways to learn, for example through audio tutorials / audiobooks or something similiar? Does anything like this exists?

Otherwise, can anyone recommend any book that is not "language specific", basically I want to learn things like what does object-oriented programming means etc etc, Free E-books which works good on Ipad would be great :)

My background is that I know computers well (been fixing computers for ppl for years) as well as webdesign (html/css and some php), but I do not really know where to start next for learning programming. I work in excel 8 hours a day so it would be fun to learn without having to sit in front of the computer all the time...

Comment: If you work in Excel, I would seriously recommend learning something like Visual Basic, because then you can apply your newly learned programming skills to your everyday work. Otherwise, if you find sitting in front of the computer programming boring, then I don't think you will gain anything from trying to learn programming.

Comment: I think this is answered here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/95876/audiobooks-for-programmers

Answer (score 3):

Hey you can download programming lessons from youtube or MIT Open course ware:  http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/video-lectures/lecture-1/

Load them on your ipod and listen to them.

Or connect it to you TV then watch while your on the couch.

It sometimes sucks being in front of the computer all the time.  Another option is to watch these videos while your on the beach.

Answer (score 1):

You can't learn to program by reading books. Especially audio books, that's not going to help at all. It's like trying to learn how to swim or play the piano by reading or listening to an audio book. You have to practice, that's the only way. I think you should start from this site to get you up and running quickly since it has step by step lectures on concepts and is quite interesting to watch: [Job Ready Programmer](http://www.jobreadyprogrammer.com)

Best of luck!

Comment: books are a great source to learn programming, you will just need to read like 10 before it all starts making sense. like when i first started with c++ by bjarne stroupstrup i can remember i wasnt able to install the gui etc